# I have problems at xhtml strict 1.0 validation

Tags: html, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

How should I fix these problems at the validation?

Error Line 15, Column 10: there is no attribute "id"
    nav id="kipozicional"

Error Line 15, Column 24: element "nav" undefined
    nav id="kipozicional"

Error Line 18, Column 8: element "header" undefined

Error Line 36, Column 6: element "main" undefined

Error Line 37, Column 9: element "article" undefined

Comment: Maybe you want to use html5 instead? `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements you are using were all introduced in HTML 5.  XHTML 1.0 is too old to support them.

Your options:

- Switch to HTML 5 (you could use the XML serialisation if you wanted)
- Replace the elements with ones in XHTML 1 (e.g. divs)
- Have invalid XHTML

I recommend switching to HTML 5.